# Get previous to max(value) when groupping in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have one table which contains trhese colums:

```
APPOINTSMENTS
|id
|worker_id
|post_id
|date
```

I can find last appointments for each worker with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id,worker_id,post_id,max(date) as date 
  FROM appointments 
  GROUP BY worker_id
)
```

How to find previous appointment (previous to last one) for each worker?  How to do it with procedure (but sqlite not supports it, but anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get the highest date for each worker.

```
SELECT 
worker_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
FROM appointments
GROUP BY worker_id
```

Then you can use this query as subquery in the next step.
Get the highest date for each worker that is lower than the actual highest date.

```
SELECT 
a.id, a.worker_id, a.post_id, MAX(a.date) AS second_highest_date
FROM appointments a
JOIN (
    SELECT 
    worker_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM appointments
    GROUP BY worker_id
) md 
ON  a.worker_id = md.worker_id 
AND a.date < md.max_date
GROUP BY a.worker_id
```

Comment: @CL. When I quote from the link you provided: "and so in many cases the value for "b" is undefined". What exactly is right about this?

Comment: @fancyPants You missed the next bit that "_Special processing occurs occurs when the aggregate function is either min() or max()_" where it says that when one of these is used (as the OP does), then all "bare" columns are taken from the same row as the row with the min/max value. (If two or more rows have the _same_ min/max, you won't know which one, but all values will be from the same row).

Comment: Okay, okay, my apologies. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method for doing this:

```
select a.*
from appointments a
where 2 = (select count(*)
           from appointments a2
           where a2.worker_id = a.worker_id and
                 a2.date >= a.date
          );
```

Assuming that the dates are unique for each "worker", this will work for the "nth" date.  The same logic can work for dates that are not unique, but you would have to clarify exactly what you want in that case.